# How to use conditon in azure data facytory integration run time

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to create an integration runtime based on condition but while deploying its not evaluate and create the IR for example in below you can see Microsoft and amazon are not the same sting hence it should not be creating this IR but still creating it . Any idea what is missing here or its not supported by syntax?

```
{
"name": "self-hosted-ir-3",
"properties": {
    "type": "SelfHosted"
},
"condition": "[equals('microsoft','amazon')]"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

We can't create IR based on certain condition. If you want to use different IR for different condition, then you need to use If activity and write the condition in the activity and then in true block call one of the IR satisfying the condition, and in false block call the other IR.